# plot histogram of every consecutive n years in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet

I have few years of daily rainfall data, like:

```
date         value
01/01/1990    1.02
02/01/1990    0.50
03/01/1990    0.00
.........     ...
.........     ...
12/12/2015    10.25
```

from which I need to make every consecutive five year histogram plot. ie, histogram of 1990 to 1995, then 1991 to 1996 and so on.. I tried using ggplot and facet, could not find a way.

```
rf_facet <- inp %>%
  filter(between(rain,1,100))

ggplot(rf_facet, aes(x = rain)) + facet_wrap(~year, nrow = 5) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill =..count..))
```

This can only produce plot for single year, I am looking for every consecutive five years.

Any help would be appreciated.
 An example data is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ouc1yqcwh0df0sz/EXAMPLE_DATA?dl=0)

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your data and code so we can try to help you

Comment: Consider sharing the code for your attempts to solve this problem so we can best help you.

Comment: the rollapply function might be helpful:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.7-13/topics/rollapply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that uses `ggplot2` and `cowplot`. I have a function that plots from year `i` to year `i+5`. I run this for all possible consecutive 5 year periods using `lapply`.

```r
# Dummy data
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('01/01/1990', format = "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                      as.Date('31/12/2000', , format = "%d/%m/%Y"), by="day"))
df$value <- runif(nrow(df), 0, 100)

# Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

# Plotting function
plot_rain <- function(i){
  g <- ggplot(df %>% filter(between(year(date), i, i+5)))
  g <- g + geom_histogram(aes(value))
  g <- g + xlab("Rainfall (mm)") + ylab("# of obs")
  g <- g + ggtitle(paste(i, i+5, sep = "-"))
}

# Run for all years
plist <- lapply(min(year(df$date)):(max(year(df$date))-5), plot_rain)

# USe cowplot to plot the list of figure
plot_grid(plotlist = plist, ncol = 2)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Exaclty! Thank you.